# How to Handle SSL certification validation in proper way?

Tags: android, ssl, android-security, trustmanager

Hello my application is live and it is using "https" protocol. The Google Play Team throws warning as below.

> "Your app(s) listed at the end of this email use an unsafe
>   implementation of the interface X509TrustManager. Specifically, the
>   implementation ignores all SSL certificate validation errors when
>   establishing an HTTPS connection to a remote host, thereby making your
>   app vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attacks. An attacker could read
>   transmitted data (such as login credentials) and even change the data
>   transmitted on the HTTPS connection. If you have more than 20 affected
>   apps in your account, please check the Developer Console for a full
>   list.
>
> To properly handle SSL certificate validation, change your code in the
>   checkServerTrusted method of your custom X509TrustManager interface to
>   raise either CertificateException or IllegalArgumentException whenever
>   the certificate presented by the server does not meet your
>   expectations. Google Play will block publishing of any new apps or
>   updates containing the unsafe implementation of the interface
>   X509TrustManager."

In my project I am using custom http client to handle HTTPS instead default httpClient. My code is as below.

```
    public static HttpClient getNewHttpClient() {
            try
            {
                KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
                trustStore.load(null, null);

                MySSLSocketFactory sf = new MySSLSocketFactory(trustStore);
                sf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

                HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
                HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
                HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, HTTP.UTF_8);

                SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
                registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
                registry.register(new Scheme("https", sf, 443));

                ClientConnectionManager ccm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, registry);

                return new DefaultHttpClient(ccm, params);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return new DefaultHttpClient();
            }
        }

public static class MySSLSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

        public MySSLSocketFactory(KeyStore truststore) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException, KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
            super(truststore);

            TrustManager tm = new X509TrustManager() {
                public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                }

                public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                }

                public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return null;
                }
            };

            sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[] { tm }, null);
        }

        @Override
        public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
            return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket(socket, host, port, autoClose);
        }

        @Override
        public Socket createSocket() throws IOException {
            return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket();
        }
    }
```

How to overcome with this problem? 
Hoping for favorable answers.

Comment: are you use webview?

Comment: No. I'm getting webservice response from https link.

Comment: Do you have any code that does what this email suggests with regard to transactions over HTTPS?  It's considered unsafe, and sometimes added by devs by accident.

Comment: @DougStevenson Or, and I suspect much more common only, 'only for testing'. It is terrifying to consider how may insecure applications may have been put into production due to these insecure `TrustManagers`. And it's great that Google is putting some effort into detecting them.

Comment: @DougStevenson , please check my edited question, I updated it with used code.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/6378872/4146722

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now that you have posted the code concerned, it is difficult to see what part of the quoted message you don't understand.

The fix is simply to *remove* the `TrustManager` part of the code altogether, root and branch, and use the default one, and then deal with whatever problems may then arise in the *proper* way, by adjusting the contents of the truststore also as to trust all the certificates you need to trust that aren't already trusted by default. If any, which there shouldn't be.

Comment: If i'll remove TrustManager part from my code then how can i deal with HTTPS  server request. Actually i'm using HTTPS webservices to post data on server.

Comment: When I post an answer I do expect it to be read beyond the first half sentence of the second paragraph.

Comment: Yes I have just removed the TrustManager part of the code and implement  HttpURLConnection instead of DefaullHttpClient.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need custom SSLSocketFactory. You can use `DefaultHttpClient` and that will handle all https by default. Just for your info, that `HttpClient` is deprecated and use  `HttpURLConnection`.

Comment: Enough with the boldface already. Use code formatting for text that is code.